# Ran out of inputの対処法とtrain_loop（）でのエラー（warnings.warn('genfromtxt: Empty input file: "%s"' % fname)）

Tags: python, python3, chainer

はじめまして。当方python初心者です。

現在こちらのサイトの作業を行なっているのですが
『ChainerのNINで自分の画像セットを深層学習させて認識させる』
http://d.hatena.ne.jp/shi3z/20150709

```sh
$ python train_imagenet.py  -g 0 -E 20000 train.txt test.txt 2>&1 | tee log
```

こちらを実行させたところ

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train_imagenet.py", line 66, in <module>
    mean_image = pickle.load(open(args.mean, 'rb'))
EOFError: Ran out of input
```

と表示されます。

使用環境は Python 3.5.2 :: Anaconda 4.2.0 (x86_64) です。

よろしくお願いします。

#### 追記

こちらの記事を見つけ、

「ChainerでcPickle.UnpicklingError」
https://qiita.com/shota_hayashi/items/4a488931ab88f45cfa55

エラー内容は違うものの実行しましたが

```
File "train_imagenet.py", line 67, in <module>
    mean_image = np.load(args.mean)
  File "~/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 392, in load
    fid.seek(-N, 1)  # back-up
IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

というエラーがでます。

#### 追記2

上記の部分

```
mean_image = np.genfromtxt('mean.npy')
```

に書き換えたところ、なんとか実行されました。しかし、

```
`~/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-4.2.0/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py:1487: UserWarning: genfromtxt: Empty input file: "mean.npy"warnings.warn('genfromtxt: Empty input file: "%s"' % fname)`
```

というエラーがでます。（エラーがでますが、ターミナルでは実行されたままです。）
train_imagenet.pyの`train_loop（）`で問題が起こっているようです。

上記の件、併せてよろしくお願いします。

#### 追記3

恐らく解決しました。

こちらの実行の直前で生成した`mean.npy`というファイルが0バイトとなっており、生成し直したところエラーがなく実行し始めました。

GPUを使用していないために、epoch 1ですがかなり時間がかかっていて（learning rate 0.01）不安ですが、とりあえずエラー無しで実行しています。
上記問題となったところは

```
mean_image = np.load(open(args.mean,'rb'))
```

このように記述して、通りました。

追記:移動してくださった方ありがとうございます！
追記2:編集ありがとうございます！見やすくなりました！

Comment: 1つ目として質問が長くなった場合は整理して書き直すかスニペットで折りたたみ圧縮するといいです。現状ですと、他の方が読みづらいかと思います。2つ目としては解決した場合は質問者でも自己回答できますので、自己回答をおこない2日後に回答を承認して下さい。

Comment: ありがとうございます。試してみます。

Answer (score 1):

こちらの実行の直前で生成したmean.npyというファイルが0バイトとなっており、生成し直したところエラーがなく実行し始めました。